# Alternatives to libvlc for receiving HTTP based MJPEG video (from Axis IP Camera)?

Tags: ip-camera, libvlc, mjpeg, intel-atom

I need to display a video stream from AXIS IP camera, which is streaming MJPEG video in HTTP. I have tried working with libvlc, but it has some buffering issues. So please suggest the list of alternatives for the same.

**System Config**: Ubuntu 11.10 operating system running on ATOM based ATMEL tablet.

Thanks in advance

BK

PS: I read a bit about gstreamer, but not sure if it's an overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, found the following alternatives (for C++ on Linux platform) to receive/display video from an IP camera:

1. **libvlc** - nice framework with good documentation; but has buffering issues
2. **opencv** - an overkill for the scenario; but otherwise a very good choice
3. **gstreamer** - an excellent framework to work with streams; but poor documentation (but consumes more CPU as compared to libvlc)

As of now, narrowed it to **gstreamer** and got some code working. Can share it, if someone is interested. Any more suggestions/alternatives are welcome.